# Community Diamond Restorer - Add the diamond back to Community's profile!

Tags: script, users

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

#### Before:

[image: before]

#### After:

[image: community has "moderator" label]

### About

This userscript, in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369868/976005), restores the "Moderator" label for the Community user, both in edit summaries and on the profile.

#### License

License: MIT.

#### Download

Download link: https://github.com/weeklyd3/sandbox/blob/master/scripts/1.user.js
Direct download: https://github.com/weeklyd3/sandbox/raw/master/scripts/1.user.js

#### Platform

I'm not sure what browsers it will work on, but I tested it in Chrome's Tampermonkey and it works fine.

### Contact

`i.hate.spam.mail.here <at> gmail.com`

### Code

**Language**: Pure JS. <sup><sub>-1 not enough jQuery</sub></sup>
**Contribute**: https://github.com/weeklyd3/sandbox/blob/master/scripts

Comment: I see you included a meme in your question. You should totally drop that and try jQuery instead.